# Por quê a aplicação pára se deixo o campo vazio?

Tags: java, android, edittext

```
public class VigMetBiapsb extends Activity {

int porctAlt, porctLarg;
double edtVaoNum;

EditText edtVao;
Button calcBiapsb;
TextView secaoBiapsb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vigmet_biapsb);

    edtVao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vao);

    calcBiapsb = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calc_biapsb);

    porctAlt = 6;
    porctLarg = 60;

    calcBiapsb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            edtVaoNum = Double.parseDouble(edtVao.getText().toString());
            if(edtVao.getText().toString().equals("")){
                secaoBiapsb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valorsec);
                secaoBiapsb.setText("Dado inválido!");
            }
            else {
                double alt = edtVaoNum * porctAlt;
                double larg = alt / 100 * porctLarg;

                secaoBiapsb = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.valorsec);
                secaoBiapsb.setText(String.valueOf(alt)+" x "+String.valueOf(larg));
             }
        }
    });

    } //fecha onCreate
}
```

Se preencho o `edtVao`, tudo é executado corretamente, mas se deixo o `edtVao` vazio, a aplicação fecha quando toco o botão `calcBiapsb`.

O trecho `edtVao.getText().toString().equals("")` dentro do `if` não deveria evitar isso? Como eu poderia checar se o campo está vazio ou não? (lembrando que o que é recebido do campo é passado para uma variável `double`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro ocorre antes da checagem que você está fazendo.

Sua aplicação fecha porque ao clicar no botão o aplicativo tenta extrair um número de tipo `double` do texto contido em `edtVao`, que está vazio. Preste atenção nesta linha:

```
edtVaoNum = Double.parseDouble(edtVao.getText().toString());
```

O conteúdo de `edtVao.getText().toString()` é uma string vazia (`""`), ou seja, que não contém um número `double` válido. Desta forma, a execução é equivalente a `Double.parseDouble("")`, que gera uma exceção do tipo `NumberFormatException`.

Procure prestar atenção no log gerado pelo erro (logcat), nele é citada qual exceção ocorreu, uma descrição do erro, e em qual linha do código ele ocorreu.

Comment: Corrigi movendo esta linha para dentro do `else`. Obrigado!